# Stackoverflow exception raised when instanciating an unmanaged class from a clr gui

Tags: c++, stack-overflow, unmanaged, managed

I'm writing a c++/clr gui to wrap around some unmanaged c++ code I am writing for testing purposes.

I use a proxy class called `HolderOfUnmanagedStuff` to instanciate the few unmanaged objects I need in my clr gui.

```
#pragma once
#include "foo.h"
namespace fooCore
{
    public class HolderOfUnmanagedStuff
    {
    public:
        HolderOfUnmanagedStuff()
        {
            foos = std::vector<fooCore::foo>();
        }
        ~HolderOfUnmanagedStuff() { }
    public:
        std::vector<fooCore::foo> foos;
        void addFoo(std::string & fileName)
        {
            whatever code on the first line    // <-- System.StackOverflowException

            foo myfoo(FileName);  // <--- when I comment those 2 lines no exception
            foos.push_back(foo);  //      but exception when I comment only this one
        }
        otherUnmanagedMembers ...
    };
}
```

My foo class uses a constructor that reads the object from a file:

```
#pragma once
namespace fooCore
{    
    class foo
    {
    public:
        foo();
        foo(std::string & fileName);
        ~foo();

         fooMembers...
    };
}
```

Whenever i try to instanciate the foo class, i get a Stack OverFlow exception with a break on the first line of the function.

The call stack only shows the logical call hierarchy: a button event, then a call to the addFoo function, and that's all

I've tried multiple solutions, rewrote every constructor, checked for unmanaged/managed conflict, pointers, addresses, references.

I've learned a lot (obviously, since i hadn't written unmanaged code for 15 years) but I can't find the issue. Any idea?

EDIT

I tried a few things :

1. added a foo member to my Holder : OK
2. trying to define that member in the constructor : exception in the constructor
3. pushing the foo member to the foo vector in the addFoo function : OK
4. defining the foo member in the addFoo : exception

The following code shows the 4 tests i made :

```
public class HolderOfUnmanagedStuff
{
    public:
        HolderOfUnmanagedStuff()
        {
            ...
            memberFoo = foo(); // TEST 2 : SOF exception on the first line of the constructor
        }
        ~HolderOfUnmanagedStuff() { }
    public:
        foo memberFoo;    // TEST 1 : No exception with that line 
        std::vector<fooCore::foo> foos;
        void addFoo(std::string & fileName)
        {
            ...               
            foos.push_back(memberFoo);  // TEST 3 No exception with that line
            memberFoo = foo();  // TEST 4 SOF on the first line of the function
        }
        otherUnmanagedMembers ...
    };
```

Comment: is `Foo` a managed class or not? the last time I used C++/CLI (long, long time ago), your code was not valid: an unmanaged class (as Foo seems to be) could not take a managed parameter as System.String^. But maybe things changed since then

Comment: I think you have an error in your foo::foo(System::String ^) constructor, which you haven’t included in the question. Also it’s a good idea to replace your push_back with emplace_back, to avoid making unneeded copy of foo.

Comment: Well, it may well be an error in the constructor, and it could very well be the use of managed objects in it, but wouldn’t I get a more explicit error ? And if so why does it compile ? When I make rookie managed/unmanaged mistakes, there are a lot of errors at compile time.

Comment: Have you checked your foo class is copyable and movable? It has to be to be as it is used in a container.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify one fact : i get the exception on the first line of any function where i instantiate a foo object, wherever that instantiation is in my code

Comment: To answer Gian Paolo & Soonts, i rewrote the constructor with everything unmanaged and checked everything again : same problem. I also tried with an empty constructor and i get the same problem. I edited the question to show the unmanaged declarations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception was due to the fact that my foo class was too big for the stack.

I modified my code so that every foo object is declared in the data segment (on the heap) by the default constructor. No more stack overflow, and the data structure is more logical.